# How to fix TypeError at /admin/pages/course/add/ in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'd done my models in `models.py` and run migrations after `makemigrations`. I'd also registered my model at `admin.py` and I can see it appearing in the admin panel. But when i clicked `add course` it gave me the following error:

```
TypeError at /admin/pages/course/add/
function missing required argument 'year' (pos 1)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/pages/course/add/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
function missing required argument 'year' (pos 1)
Exception Location: C:\Users\ahnaa\OneDrive\Documents\Web Developent\Django\school_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in get_default, line 829
Python Executable:  C:\Users\ahnaa\OneDrive\Documents\Web Developent\Django\school_app\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\ahnaa\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Web Developent\\Django\\school_app',
 'C:\\Users\\ahnaa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\ahnaa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\ahnaa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\ahnaa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\ahnaa\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Web '
 'Developent\\Django\\school_app\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\ahnaa\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Web '
 'Developent\\Django\\school_app\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 21 Jun 2020 19:50:52 +0600
```

Comment: can you please post your model

Answer (score 0):

In your course model, go to year model and set null= True, blank=True
year = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
Make sure you do not have arguments there which you do not recognize.